# Version string portion was too short or too long - Azure

Tags: azure

I uploaded a project on Windows Azure Websites, and I am getting a strange error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Version string portion was too short or too long.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.]
   System.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument) +10913423
   System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result) +424
   System.Version.Parse(String input) +68
   System.Version..ctor(String version) +23
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.WebPagesDeployment.GetVersionFromConfig(NameValueCollection appSettings) +73
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.WebPagesDeployment.GetVersion(String path, NameValueCollection appSettings) +28
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.StartCore(Version testVersion) +34
   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +70

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Version string portion was too short or too long..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +547
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Version string portion was too short or too long..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36213
```

Running the website locally in IIS works fine.   A search on Google didn't return much.  Any ideas what this error could be about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to some mixed-up `<assemblyBinding>` redirects in web.config.  Apparently these were being added by NuGet or some process.  I removed all assemblyBindings and then re-added only the essential, and this error went away. Strange, but worked.